# Sound is not working correctly on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

I know this is my own fault. But what i did was this
first i wrote this command '*sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio*' and then i wrote again '*sudo apt-get install pulseaudio*' and now the sound doesn't work properly
[image: Sound Settings]

And the Indicator doesn't work either, it's just grayed out. The shortcuts are not working either.
[image]

Alsamixer is working, and this is the only way i change change the volume at the moment:
[image]

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf1c00000 irq 52


jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib conf.c:1686:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:11:0:Unexpected end of file
ALSA lib conf.c:3406:(config_file_open) /etc/asound.conf may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it
/usr/bin/pulseaudio: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-1.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC665 Analog [ALC665 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC665 Digital [ALC665 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

VLC sound is not working, am getting this error:
[image]

Comment: Is this a user specific issue or a system wide issue?  Create a new account and test with that?  Also you've got various comments below with stuff you have tried.  Please can you add these back into your  question because its quite difficult to follow what you have done.

Comment: I had [similar problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225444/how-to-make-pulseaudio-work-again) recently, maybe it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I'm unable to comment, so I'm putting my comment into this answer.

Could you open a terminal (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> by default) and enter the command `alsamixer`? You should see a bunch of volume levels. Make sure they are towards the top of their bars and unmuted ("OO" is unmuted, "MM" is muted at the bottom of each bar).

If it doesn't look like anything's wrong, could you post a screenshot of the alsamixer window?

Comment: jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

Comment: Paste output of these: `cat /proc/asound/cards`, `aplay -l`, `lsmod | grep snd`

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's going on, but running the following script could be useful to someone more knowledgeable than me. `wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh` -- it'll offer to upload the information to their servers for easy sharing if you want, or it can print it.

Comment: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=403d74ac5b083e74986ee9049811f6542bcfcb16

Comment: One potential issue is that PulseAudio isn't running. There is some info [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio) about it. You could try starting it with `service pulseaudio start`, not sure whether that'll work.

Comment: I tried **sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins "pulseaudio-*" paman padevchooser paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter** and rebooted and now the sound works but indicator and shortcuts doesn't and the sound settings are empty like the image shows

Answer (score 1):

When you removed pulseaudio, all packages that depended on it will have been removed. I guess this is the issue.

So, reinstalling pulseaudio alone will not do - it only contains the pulseaudio sound server.

On my comp, searching for pulseaudio in software center returned the following installed packages. Try installing them and see if that solves your problem.

libcanberra-pulse
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio-utils
pulseadio-module-gconf
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
libpulse0
libpulse-mainloop-glib0
libpulsedsp
pulseaudio
libsdl1.2debian
indicator-sound
pulseaudio-module-x11

Of course, you may not need all these packages (gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio for instance).

Alternatively open software center and look into your history. You'll be able to find out what packages were uninstalled along with pulseaudio. Install them and check.

Comment: i got this error 'E: Unable to locate package pulseadio-module-gconf' but then i removed the pulseaudio-module-gconf from there and installed all them successfully, but after rebooting it didn't change anything :(

Comment: I'm just gonna reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: pulseudio-module-gconf seems unimportant. Open Software Center > History > Removals > 'The date of uninstall of pulseaudio' and check if something else was removed. My search result may not have returned all dependent packages.

Comment: I also tried that, and tried to install them but didn't help either, but i have reinstalled ubuntu now, and now i have 12.10 :D thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Sorry I couldn't solve your problem. But there are some smart people out there you know. You should probably have waited for the bounty to end, i.e., till your question left the featured section. Doesn't matter now that everything is working. Cheers.

Comment: yeah, sorry and as you can see this question has been on for almost a month and i really needed to fix this and i couldn't wait anymore. i can give you the points but leave the question unaccepted

Comment: That will be unnecessary! All I meant was that now that the question is in the featured section, you'd expect someone to crack it.

Answer (score 0):

#### try this..

open your terminal and type

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-sound-applet
```

it will uninstall the gnome-sound-applet and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and quickest way to fix this problem.
Open Terminal and then just copy and paste this

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the basic settings are correct:
System tools > System settings > Sound > Output volume to **on**

Comment: Sorry but I'm sure OP already checked that.