# Why does my skype crash?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, skype

Skype worked great since i installed it when OMG!Ubuntu! came with that [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/skype-for-linux-adds-windows-live-login-fresh-login-screen) article. but randomly now it doesn't work.

when i type skype into the terminal i get this:

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ skype
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(skype:10592): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(skype:10592): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(skype:10592): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(skype:10592): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so

/usr/bin/pulseaudio: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-1.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/pulseaudio: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-1.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
*** glibc detected *** skype: free(): invalid pointer: 0xf766eef0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xf4951ee2]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2(snd_config_substitute+0x6d)[0xf766960d]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2(+0x22158)[0xf766b158]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2(snd_config_update_r+0x229)[0xf766bdc9]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2(snd_config_update+0x48)[0xf766c358]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2(snd_pcm_open+0x3f)[0xf768dd2f]
skype[0x92354d6]
skype[0x9235dd9]
skype[0x908dc79]
skype[0x8ef3c67]
skype[0x8ef2b81]
skype[0x8e9c52a]
skype[0x8e9c40e]
skype[0x8edfe5e]
skype[0x8ddea3e]
skype[0x8deca5f]
skype[0x8b24455]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-09ac4000 rwxp 00000000 08:06 19403540                           /usr/bin/skype
09ac5000-09b42000 r-xp 01a7c000 08:06 19403540                           /usr/bin/skype
09b42000-09b54000 rwxp 01af9000 08:06 19403540                           /usr/bin/skype
09b54000-09bf4000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
0ba37000-0c3c1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
ddafd000-ddafe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ddafe000-de2fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
de2fe000-de2ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
de2ff000-deaff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e0900000-e09fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e09fe000-e0a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e0b00000-e0bfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e0bfe000-e0c00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e0c00000-e0cfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e0cfe000-e0d00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e0d00000-e0dcc000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e0dcc000-e0e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e0e00000-e0efe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e0efe000-e0f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e0f00000-e0ffe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e0ffe000-e1000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1000000-e10ce000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e10ce000-e1100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1aff000-e1b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1b00000-e2300000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e2300000-e23fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e23fe000-e2400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2500000-e25fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e25fe000-e2600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2600000-e26fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e26fe000-e2700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2700000-e27fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e27fe000-e2800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2800000-e28fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e28fe000-e2900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2900000-e29fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e29fe000-e2a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2a00000-e2afe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e2afe000-e2b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2b00000-e2bfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e2bfe000-e2c00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2c00000-e2cfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e2cfe000-e2d00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2d00000-e2dfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e2dfe000-e2e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2e00000-e2efe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e2efe000-e2f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e2f00000-e2ffe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e2ffe000-e3000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3000000-e30fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e30fe000-e3100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3100000-e31fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e31fe000-e3200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3b00000-e3bfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e3bfe000-e3c00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3c00000-e3cfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e3cfe000-e3d00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3d00000-e3dfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e3dfe000-e3e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3e00000-e3efe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e3efe000-e3f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e3f00000-e3ffe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e3ffe000-e4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4000000-e40fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e40fe000-e4100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4100000-e41fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e41fe000-e4200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e42ff000-e4300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4300000-e4b00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10616]
e4b00000-e4bfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e4bfe000-e4c00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4d00000-e4dfe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e4dfe000-e4e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4e00000-e4efe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e4efe000-e4f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e4f00000-e4ffe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e4ffe000-e5000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5000000-e50fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e50fe000-e5100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5100000-e51fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e51fe000-e5200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5200000-e52fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e52fe000-e5300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5300000-e53fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e53fe000-e5400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5500000-e5600000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e5600000-e56f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e56f1000-e5700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5700000-e57ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e57ff000-e5800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5800000-e58f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e58f1000-e5900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5900000-e59f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e59f1000-e5a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5a00000-e5af1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e5af1000-e5b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5b00000-e5bf1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e5bf1000-e5c00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5c00000-e5cf1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e5cf1000-e5d00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5d00000-e5df1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e5df1000-e5e00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5e00000-e5ef1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e5ef1000-e5f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e5f00000-e5ff1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e5ff1000-e6000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6000000-e60f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e60f1000-e6100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6100000-e61f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e61f1000-e6200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6200000-e62f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e62f1000-e6300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6300000-e63f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e63f1000-e6400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6400000-e64f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e64f1000-e6500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6500000-e65f1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e65f1000-e6600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e666d000-e666e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e666e000-e6e6e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e6e6e000-e6e6f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e6e6f000-e78bb000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10612]
e7989000-e798a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e7997000-e79db000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 10879065                           /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf
e7a3b000-e7a3f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e7aad000-e7ab1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e7aca000-e7bca000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e7bd8000-e7cf8000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e7e44000-e8254000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e8254000-e8255000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8255000-e8b55000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10611]
e8b55000-e8ce7000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 17695016                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
e8ce7000-e8cf6000 r-xp 00192000 08:06 17695016                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
e8cf6000-e8cfd000 rwxp 001a1000 08:06 17695016                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
e8cfd000-e8d00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e8d00000-e8e00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e8efe000-e8eff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e8eff000-e96ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10609]
e96ff000-e9700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
e9700000-e9f00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10608]
e9f00000-e9f45000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e9f45000-ea000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea0fe000-ea0ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea0ff000-ea8ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10607]
ea8ff000-ea900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ea900000-eb100000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10606]
eb100000-eb1fd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
eb1fd000-eb200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb200000-eb2fd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
eb2fd000-eb300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb300000-eb321000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
eb321000-eb400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb49e000-eb4fe000 rwxs 00000000 00:04 6422542                            /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
eb4fe000-eb4ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb4ff000-ebcff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10615]
ebcff000-ebd00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ebd00000-ec500000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10604]
ec500000-ec5ed000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
ec5ed000-ec600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ec645000-ec6fe000 rwxs 00000000 00:04 6389773                            /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
ec6fe000-ec6ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ec6ff000-eceff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10603]
eceff000-ecf00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ecf00000-ed700000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10602]
ed700000-ed7d0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
ed7d0000-ed800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ed800000-ed8f8000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
ed8f8000-ed900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ed900000-ed9ed000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
ed9ed000-eda00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eda2c000-eda7e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 20188577                           /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf
edaff000-edb00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
edb00000-ee300000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10610]
ee300000-ee3ed000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
ee3ed000-ee400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ee434000-ee439000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 17694947                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.15.so
ee439000-ee43a000 r-xp 00004000 08:06 17694947                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.15.so
ee43a000-ee43b000 rwxp 00005000 08:06 17694947                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.15.so
ee45d000-ee461000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
ee486000-ee4b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23209512                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-qt.so.2.6.0
ee4b8000-ee4b9000 r-xp 00031000 08:06 23209512                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-qt.so.2.6.0
ee4b9000-ee4ba000 rwxp 00032000 08:06 23209512                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-qt.so.2.6.0
ee4dc000-ee4fa000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4200301                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/systemtrayicon/libsni-qt.so
ee4fa000-ee4fb000 r-xp 0001e000 08:06 4200301                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/systemtrayicon/libsni-qt.so
ee4fb000-ee4fc000 rwxp 0001f000 08:06 4200301                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/systemtrayicon/libsni-qt.so
ee4fc000-ee4fd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ee4fd000-eecfd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10600]
eed00000-eeded000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
eeded000-eee00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eee03000-eee15000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 20188634                           /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n019004l.pfb
eee15000-eee6c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 20188582                           /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf
eee6c000-eee97000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23209498                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so
eee97000-eee98000 r-xp 0002a000 08:06 23209498                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so
eee98000-eee99000 rwxp 0002b000 08:06 23209498                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so
eee99000-eeea5000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23209499                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so
eeea5000-eeea6000 r-xp 0000b000 08:06 23209499                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so
eeea6000-eeea7000 rwxp 0000c000 08:06 23209499                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so
eeea7000-eeef6000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 17695017                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
eeef6000-eeef7000 ---p 0004f000 08:06 17695017                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
eeef7000-eeef9000 r-xp 0004f000 08:06 17695017                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
eeef9000-eeefd000 rwxp 00051000 08:06 17695017                           /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
eeefd000-eeefe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eeefe000-ef6fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10599]
ef6fe000-ef6ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
ef6ff000-efeff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10598]
efeff000-eff00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
eff00000-f0700000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10597]
f0700000-f0721000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f0721000-f0800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f0800000-f0821000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f0821000-f0900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f0900000-f0921000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f0921000-f0a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f0a06000-f0a44000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23209497                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so
f0a44000-f0a45000 r-xp 0003e000 08:06 23209497                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so
f0a45000-f0a46000 rwxp 0003f000 08:06 23209497                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so
f0a46000-f0aa6000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23209514                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.4
f0aa6000-f0aa8000 r-xp 0005f000 08:06 23209514                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.4
f0aa8000-f0aa9000 rwxp 00061000 08:06 23209514                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.4
f0aa9000-f0afc000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23209488                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8.1
f0afc000-f0afd000 r-xp 00052000 08:06 23209488                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8.1
f0afd000-f0afe000 rwxp 00053000 08:06 23209488                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8.1
f0afe000-f0aff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f0aff000-f12ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10596]
f12ff000-f1300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f1300000-f1b00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:10595]
f1b00000-f1bed000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f1bed000-f1c00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f1c22000-f1c42000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f1c42000-f1c77000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 23209302                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblcms.so.1.0.19
f1c77000-f1c78000 r-xp 00034000 08:06 23209302                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblcms.so.1.0.19
f1c78000-f1c79000 rwxp 00035000 08:06 23209302                           /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblcms.so.1.0.19Aborted (core dumped)
```

I get logged in for 1-2 seconds or so but then it closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*** glibc detected *** skype: free(): invalid pointer: 0xf766eef0 ***
```

means that Skype is freeing memory using a pointer it should not use, for example because it is a null pointer. In other words: programming error. It seems to be related to some operations done in the sound system as can be seen in the backtrace.

I suspect that this is just a bug in Skype which only they can debug (no source available).

Therefore I suggest to file a bug on their bug tracker including this information: [Skype Client for Linux](https://jira.skype.com/browse/SCL)

Comment: ah thanks, i have been having problems with my sounds.. http://askubuntu.com/q/218902/34385 im just gonna wait when i get my sound working correctly and then I'll try again, if it still fails im gonna report it.

Comment: Yeah, that could be related. However, Skype really shouldn't crash that way. If it can be tricked into crashing on purpose this can be a potential security issue.