# No sound after Xubuntu-desktop installation

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio

I had, initially, a Ubuntu installation running completely fine. Compiz bugged, then I switched to LXQT.

LXQt bugged between sessions, then I switched to KDE. KDE bugged on some applications, then I switched to XFCE (at the moment).

Sound worked fine between all those transitions up until now. When I finally installed and rebooted my PC, sound was gone.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on the XFCE Enviroment. Switching to another session/enviroment doesn't work.

What I've done already:

- Reinstall alsa and pulseaudio (purging)
- Add a string line at the end of alsa.conf
- Check if my audio drivers are being detected
- Try unmuting sound values on the xfce4-mixer
- Purging pulseaudio and trying to work with only alsa
- General information I found on the similar topics didn't work either
- Tweaking values on alsamixer

Any help would be appreciated. As I said, problem started when I installed Xubuntu.

I was told to remove xfce4-mixer but I had to uninstall the xfce4 package along it, should I proceed?

EDIT: Some SSes and pastebin/ryUuDpEr, pastebin/e6KLYf5D

Some screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: do you have a file for /etc/pulse/default.pa? if not, copy and paste the contents of this http://pastebin.com/EJ2qvZvA to make that file, save it as /etc/pulse/default.pa and reboot. I HATE it when that happens, it's sooo annoying.

Comment: See this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/225444/how-to-make-pulseaudio-work-again

Comment: Try with sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`

Comment: Hey, the default.pa thing didn't work. I already had a file with that name created at the directory, changed it's name and replaced with the pastebin version... Didn't solve.
Neither did the linux-headers.
http://pastebin.com/GCeKzMj8

Comment: Remove pulseaudio (sudo apt-get remove  pulseaudio) , reboot and test (you will then use alsa layer only). Also remove the line you add in alsa.conf (but did you test "generic" ?)

Comment: Hey, I was able to narrow down my problem and posted it below! As I said in the main post, I've already tried to work around with only ALSA and it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

I resolve with pavucontrol.

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Select the device and remove mute sound.

Comment: omg, you provided the simplest and oneliner that solve the thing for me:   just need one tool to let me choose all the different audio configuration:   in my case, pavucontrol - i switch the output device from analog output to headphone as output.   Thanks.

Comment: you're my savior.. `xfce-mixer` hanging, `pavucontrol` runs fast XD

Answer (score 3):

**OP HERE**

Aswering because I've been able to narrow down my problem.

It seems like Xubuntu comes with Pulseaudio by default. It seems like Pulseaudio overrode my ALSA native settings, becoming the main output device. The problem here is that PulseAudio won't detect my onboard audio chip, only the GPU one that I won't use.

If I try to uninstall Pulseaudio, however, ALSA won't naturally take his place. I tried to open a music on VLC to test after uninstallid pulse and it said "No default output device ...".

So I need to do either:

1. Force PA to recognize my onboard card
2. Uninstall PA and make it my default device for outputting sound

I can't play a sound with aplay, by the way.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCinI.png

EDIT: Solved using this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2186531