# No sound after installing Gnome3 on Ubuntu 12.04.5

Tags: gnome, soundcard

I recently performed a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04.5 to cure a few problems, including only having 'dummy output' for sound. After re-install the sound worked fine right up until I installed Gnome 3 on my desktop. After that, sound settings listed only dummy output for a sound card. Using alsa-mixer from the command line shows the proper sound card, but I still could not get any sound from the speakers. I tried updating the alsa drivers, with no luck. I also purged the Gnome ppa from the computer, uninstalled Gnome, and still had the same problem. I had to re-install Ubuntu again to get the sound card working. I would appreciate any help on this since I much prefer the Gnome desktop to Unity.

Comment: do you have a file /etc/pulse/default.pa? if not see here http://askubuntu.com/a/225499/167115

Comment: I do have /etc/pulse/default.pa, but I have recently re-loaded Ubuntu and have not installed the Gnome desktop yet so I can keep the audio working.

Comment: Apparently losing the sound card is not Gnome's fault. I just rebooted my computer, and I am only showing dummy output now for sound. Have not made any changes, and it was working earlier.

Comment: see if any of these help http://askubuntu.com/questions/294016/no-sound-in-ubuntu-13-04-only-dummy-output-device-listed

Comment: and try `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel`

Comment: this might help http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/491346/how-do-i-get-my-sound-working

Comment: `sudo service pulseaudio stop` then `sudo alsa force reload` and finally `sudo service pulseaudio start`

Comment: I had tried the pulseaudio stop, force reload and pulseaudio start before without success, but I just tried the modprobe snd-hda-intel, and that one worked. Thank you very much. That saves me from having to start windows for school work.