# Sound (tray and audio) problem made worse

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, system-tray

I had a "dummy output" problem and started messing with the terminal. After trying multiple users' solutions I decided to uninstall pulseaudio and use alsamixer instead. That didn't fix my issue, rather it just got rid of the volume system tray that I would like to get back.

I used `sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio` to uninstall then `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` to re-install but all of my issues are still the same, and the system tray volume icon isn't back after re-booting either.

How do I get my sound devices to output properly and the volume tray back?

Also, the hdmi output disappeared from PulseAudio Volume Control.

Comment: Also, when you have a dummy output problem, see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/491346/how-do-i-get-my-sound-working

Comment: I can't get past the first command as the terminal throws back `Failed to stop pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service not loaded.
` (first command being `sudo service pulseaudio stop`)

Comment: Then keep going. It can't restart if it's not started.

Comment: `Failed to start pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service not found.`

Comment: Just ignore the service commands as the newer versions of ubuntu don't seem to run that as a service anymore.

Comment: did all the commands (saved the file after changing it) and rebooted but still nothing but dummy output

Comment: I added instructions for newer users on the other answer.

Comment: Yes! :D The system icon tray is back! Upvoted your answer on the other thread, now to fix this dummy output issue. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, a simple run of the following command:

```
apt-cache search pulse | egrep 'tray|indicator'
```

returns the following:

```
indicator-sound - System sound indicator.
indicator-sound-gtk2 - System sound indicator.
pasystray - PulseAudio controller for the system tray
pnmixer - Simple mixer application for system tray
volti - control audio volume from system tray/notification area
```

Although, I think what you are looking for is `indicator-sound` as the tray icons are called indicators for unity. In any case, run the following command to hopefully install the system tray icon you are looking for:

```
sudo apt-get install pasystray pnmixer volti indicator-sound
```

reboot.

If you are using unity, you might be able to skip a reboot by running the following command:

```
indicator-sound &
```

---

**For Kubuntu:**

Run the following command to install the systray icon:

```
sudo apt-get install kmix
```

Start it up using the following command:

```
kmix &
```

Comment: I get almost the same output (only volti is in a different line) `indicator-sound - System sound indicator.
volti - control audio volume from system tray/notification area
indicator-sound-gtk2 - System sound indicator.
pasystray - PulseAudio controller for the system tray
pnmixer - Simple mixer application for system tray
` after inputting the second code in the terminal and rebooting, the volume is not back on the system tray

Comment: @HelpMeee What does it return when you run `indicator-sound &` on a unity desktop.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using kubuntu (kde desktop environment) so it just returns `indicator-sound: command not found
`

Comment: @HelpMeee I added some new instructions here and I also added some new instructions on the other answer.

Comment: `name@name-desktop:~$ plasma-pa &
[1] 3494
name@name-desktop:~$ plasma-pa: command not found`
(there's a line break before and after "[1] 3494" in the terminal, not something I inputted)

Comment: I did, thats what it outputted. Tried again now after rebooting and still same result

Comment: @HelpMeee I see, I have changed the commands to use kmix instead.

Comment: `name@name-desktop:~$ kmix &
[1] 3531
name@name-desktop:~$ QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
KGlobal::locale(): Warning your global KLocale is being recreated with a valid main component instead of a fake component, this usually means you tried to call i18n related functions before your main component was created. You should not do that since it most likely will not work
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.`

Comment: @HelpMeee This is supposed to be for the system icon tray so if it's already working then . . . Also, those are warnings and can be ignored if working.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry! I thought this was supposed to fix the dummy output problem. I now have two system trays that differ in UI xD

(KDE mixer was never there before, but I think its better than the other one anyway, might be useful to have both)

Comment: @HelpMeee You should ask the dummy output problem as a separate question to get that addressed, thanks.

Comment: @HelpMeee To get rid of the second tray icon, you can uninstall kmix.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Posted separate question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output