# Persistent Dummy Output

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard, kde-apps

The soundcard I want to use is detected and works (it only recently switched to dummy output and didn't allow me to go back).

HDMI is no longer listed under Audio and Video - KDE Control Module; everything under audio module is set to dummy output and its the only 'soundcard' on the list now. I can view my previous sound cards in alsamixer, but changing the settings from there does nothing.

How can I get my real soundcards to work again?

I have already tried the following answers without success:

[How do I get my sound working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491346/how-do-i-get-my-sound-working)

**EDIT:**

```
name@name-desktop:~$ lspci -vvv | grep -A8 Audio
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 43
        Region 0: Memory at ff764000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation FCH Azalia Controller
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=slow >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
        Region 0: Memory at ff760000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Could this image possibly help?:

[image]

There is another soundcard but I'm unsure of what its for because it never outputs sound, but it does have a lot of settings: that sound card is labelled as "HD-Audio Generic".

[image]

[image]

So I went into Software & Updates under the Additional drivers tab and I see this:

[image]

It was on *Do not use the device* so I changed it and applied the settings but unfortunately the soundcard isn't back even after reboot.

Comment: What type of computer do you have?

Comment: Built it myself so its custom; which parts were you concerned about?

Comment: Well,  I saw this other answer related to dell http://askubuntu.com/questions/460035/dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1

Comment: Please run the following command and post the output in your question to help, thanks. `lspci -vvv | grep -A8 Audio`

Comment: Try running the following command and then reboot: `usermod -a -G audio $USER`

Comment: Yes, that is your hdmi output and it looks like it should be running and on. As it is digital out, there should be no level.

Comment: it returned this `usermod: Permission denied.
usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.` but I'll reboot now to see if it took effect

Comment: Sorry, you probably need to use sudo.

Comment: Also, try the following: `rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*` reboot

Comment: Can you please also post a screenshot (or two) of the other sound card?

Comment: Ran both and rebooted yet nothing has changed (still dummy output with no other displayed soundcards to change to) will get screenshots of other soundcard and upload in a minute

Comment: Pictures are up (not sure if it notifies you)

Comment: Disable "automute". Also, it looks like sound is working as far as alsa is concerned. Have you tried playing music?

Comment: I disabled it right now, and tested a video on youtube and that didn't work, neither did the sound from a video installed on my hardware nor system sounds (test) because its still selecting dummy output. **Something that should be mentioned is that whenever I increase dummy input sound volume from the tray then open pulseaudio volume control, it raises the same volume percentage in silence.**

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` and then `pavucontrol &` are you able to enable the card from these controls?

Comment: I used to be able to, before dummy output appeared. s: now it just reverses any volume increase to silence. Its still not showing up.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Comment: Apparently, there's nothing wrong with the ALSA drivers (`speaker-test` should work with the HDMI device; does it?). There appears to be something wrong with PulseAudio not willing to use it.

Comment: The speaker test always worked with the HDMI, but now hdmi won't even show up in the Audio and Video - KDE Control Module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a solution to this so I just re-installed Kubuntu and the sound works perfect.

Downside: wiped everything else (but I didn't have much on my ssd so it was fine)

Comment: That's like saying "My tire went flat, so I bought a new car"

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what's the problem or why it happens, but that worked for me.

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Answer (score 9):

First, replace any previous configurations:

```
sudo apt update
sudo rm -R /etc/pulse/*
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install pulseaudio
```

Then, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
rm -r ~/.config/pulse*
pulseaudio -k
```

[source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309373)

---

If alsa is somehow messed up, then running the following commands may fix the issue:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install libasound2 libasound2-data libasound2-dev libasound2-plugin-smixer libatopology-dev libatopology2 alsa-utils pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.config/pulse*
pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: PulseAudio Sound Server is now in place of Dummy output in the Audio and Video - KDE Control Module as a audio playback device , but it still says "Dummy output" in the tray, but that might be just a display issue.. not sure. Either way, system sound test still outputs no audio. Also my original soundcards are still not back. I actually had the PulseAudio Sound Server situation before, and thats what made me try to uninstall it.

Comment: I'll reboot in about two hours to look for improvements (currently waiting for files to finish downloading).

Comment: Rebooting actually changed the PulseAudio Sound Server back to Dummy Output :( Sorry to disappoint

Comment: @HelpMeee Try running commands 2, 3, & 4. According to the thread, some people have to modprobe snd-hda-intel after every boot.

Comment: Yes, its back to PulseAudio Sound Server, but its still Dummy Output everywhere else and there's no sound.

Comment: @HelpMeee Did you see the new default.pa file I posted at http://askubuntu.com/questions/491346/how-do-i-get-my-sound-working It's listed under "*Alternatively, this is the /etc/pulse/default.pa for 16.04*"

Comment: Yes, replaced everything in that file again after you updated it, unfortunately there's hadn't been a change.

Comment: @HelpMeee For good measure, I have included some new instructions.

Comment: @HelpMeee I have updated the instructions again as I saw a typo.

Comment: Same thing as before: "PulseAudio Sound Server is now in place of Dummy output in the Audio and Video - KDE Control Module as a audio playback device , but it still says "Dummy output" in the tray," also still have to re-run that code in the terminal everytime after rebooting to keep it that way

Comment: @HelpMeee Do you have ATI graphics as well, you may need the proprietary driver which would also include the sound driver for HDMI?

Comment: @HelpMeee Open up the kubuntu-driver-manager and see if there are any recommended proprietary drivers such as fglrx that are available for you and then reboot if you make any changes.

Comment: Only one, and I applied it and rebooted yet there doesn't seem to be a change (in the picture I just added). The official driver manager for KDE seems useless because all it says is "Collecting information about your system" (didn't upload a picture of it).

Answer (score 1):

#### For those using the `snd_hda_intel` module

1. Check if you are using the `snd_hda_intel` kernel module:

   ```bsh
   lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
   lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
   ```
2. If so, add two lines (you may need only the first line) to `alsa-base.conf` using the commands below.

   ```bsh
   echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   ```

NOTE: It was suggested to also add a third line but my system worked without me adding it. Add that using this command:

```bsh
echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

REF: [Fix No Sound (Dummy Output) Issue In Ubuntu With SND HDA Intel](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was caused by one application that locked the sound device. In my case, it was `mplayer`, but it could be something else for you. To get a list of these applications, run:

```
# fuser -v /dev/snd/*
                     USER       PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  ...      899378 F.... mplayer
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p:   ...      899378 F...m mplayer
/dev/snd/timer:      ...      899378 f.... mplayer
```

After stopping that application, I forced a restart of pulseaudio:

```
/usr/bin/pulseaudio -k && sleep 1 && /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
```

For more details, please check the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#The_only_device_shown_is_%22dummy_output%22_or_newly_connected_cards_are_not_detected), where I found the trick:

> The only device shown is "dummy output" or newly connected cards are not detected
>
> If the only playback device is the Dummy Output, PulseAudio cannot access your  sound devices. It is possible there is an issue with logind giving permissions, see General troubleshooting#Session permissions for more information.
>
> An application might also not have been configured to work with PulseAudio. This  happens with FluidSynth for example. To see which application is responsible for  a direct access to the sound card via alsa, run the following command:
>
> `# fuser -v /dev/snd/*`
>
> Try to close these applications. pulseaudio, if running, should take again precedence over these applications and all the applications relying on pulseaudio should work again like expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  This solved the problem for me - and it was indeed fluidsynth causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Today - seemingly having the same problem - I did the following, using Synaptic package manager:

Reinstalled the following packages:

```
linux-sound-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5)
pulseaudio (1:8.0-0ubuntu3)
```

... and my card is back available.

Edit: problem came back after reboot!

Edit2: minimal (temporary) remedy is `sudo dpkg-reconfigure pulseaudio`

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers**. You will find a driver similar to **audio:** set it to *Do not use this device*.  Then  apply changes  and restart.

Then system will use the inbuilt audio

If not working check whether it has changed by repeating the above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

**Settings > Multimedia > Audio Volume > Advanced** and there switching around between **4.1** and **Analog Stereo Output/Duplex**

Sound is back...

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about analog stereo, a very simple solution is to use a C-Media USB audio device. My built in audio card is just not detected. The problem may be with my motherboard because it used to work. If I wanted to use 5.1 I guess I could buy a card.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many different causes of this problem, but I'll give an answer for my particular situation.  I started experiencing this after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04.  The problem turned out to be permissions.  My account was in the `pulse-access` group in `/etc/group`.  For 18.04, this was sufficient.  It appears that for Ubuntu 20.04 there was a change such that the account must now be in the `pulse` group instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my E200 HA by putting the following lines in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel mode="olpc-xo-1_5"
```

The first stopped the dummy output and got the soundcard recognised, but I had to put in the second line as sound was coming out of both speakers and headphones at the same time.