# Sound stopped working, "dummy output"

Tags: 16.04, sound, soundcard

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. From a few days back I can't hear the sound on my laptop. While checking sound settings It shows Dummy output on the section of Output tab. How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: do real shutdown (from windows if you have dual boot), post aplay -l result

Comment: aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persistent Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output)