# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS dummy output

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

So my device output was working fine until one day suddenly it just said dummy output. I then mistakenly upgraded Ubuntu as well. Until recently Bluetooth headphones were working but now even they have stopped working. Only wired headphones are working.
I tried pulse audio purge remove, `killall`, start, remove `~/.config/pulse`, `alsa force-reload`, and rebooting my device but none of the methods have fixed my dummy output problem.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
```

gives no output

and no sound cards are detected

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

returns no sound cards

Apologize if questions is framed in wrong or incorrect way, it's my first time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persistent Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove timidity
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Please consider elaborating your answer indicating why do you think your suggested methodology should work.