# How to analyze the source of "Dummy output" device showing up?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a Dummy Output appearing in my Output Devices and no sound works. I already read lots of questions on this site, but no proposed soltion worked for me persistently.

## Diagnostics

### `lspci -nnk | grep -A3`

```
06:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1637]
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5082]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
06:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [17aa:5084]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
        Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x
06:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
        Subsystem: Lenovo Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [17aa:5082]
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

### `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

### `fuser -v /dev/snd/*`

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  jonas      1176 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC2:  jonas      1176 F.... pulseaudio
```

### `find /lib/modules | grep snd | grep hda | grep intel`

```
/lib/modules/5.4.0-52-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel/snd-sof-intel-hda.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-52-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel/snd-sof-intel-hda-common.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-52-generic/kernel/sound/soc/intel/boards/snd-soc-skl_hda_dsp.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-52-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-52-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel/snd-sof-intel-hda.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/soc/sof/intel/snd-sof-intel-hda-common.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/soc/intel/boards/snd-soc-skl_hda_dsp.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
/lib/modules/5.8.0-25-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko
```

## Here is what I tried:

### 1. `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`

If I issue this command often enough (roughly around 3-7 times), then eventually my speakers appear as an output device and sound works. However, after rebooting, this does not work again.

How can I make this consistent?

Typical output of this command looks like

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-dmic snd-acp3x-rn snd-acp3x-pdm-dma snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-rawmidi snd-hda-core snd-seq snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-device snd-rn-pci-acp3x snd-pci-acp3x snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-soc-dmic snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-dmic snd-acp3x-rn snd-acp3x-pdm-dma snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-rawmidi snd-hda-core snd-seq snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-device snd-rn-pci-acp3x snd-pci-acp3x snd-timer.
```

Sometimes, the `failed: modules still loaded` part does not appear. But I did not recognize any different outcome.

This slightly changes `aplay -l` to

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

so for `card 1` it now is `Subdevices: 0/1` instead of `Subdevices: 1/1`.

### 2. adding lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base`

According to the solution in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800262/persistent-dummy-output) I added the line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base`. This actually replaces the `Dummy output` by `HD-Audio Generic Digital Stereo (HDMI)`. I guess this enables the HDMI audio output? I can't test this, but the speaker does not work.

This changed the output of `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The other two proposed lines

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
blacklist snd_soc_skl
```

don't have any effect that I recognized.

### 3. Timidity

Some people had problems with the program `timidity`, but it's not installed on my system.

I'm pretty clueless, what to do now. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the same or a similar problem. Does work after `sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio` or `pactl load-module module-detect`. But problem reappear after every reboot.

Also seen people suggest to edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` by uncommenting:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0 <-- change this to 0,0
```

Didn't work for me though.

Comment: I am in the same boat, at least you have a partial fix!  The `pactl load-module module-detect` line works for me, only a temporary fix until either the next boot or sometimes it flakes out.  But at least it works!

Comment: So I took a look at `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and it seems like the command `load-module module-detect` is inside some `if` construction, so it is not necessarily executed. Instead it uses `load-module module-udev-detect`. Adding the line `load-module module-detect` outside of the if statement worked for me :)

Comment: On the other hand, `module-detect` seems to be [deprecated](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=831355)...

Comment: For me `pactl load-module module-udef-detect` return `Failure: Module initialization failed`. The if-else statement in `default.pa` run `load-module module-udef-detect` if it exist but `load-module module-detect` otherwise. So if it exist but fail, well, we get our no detected sound problem... Ended up creating a startup script running `pactl load-module module-detect` since I suspect an update may revert `default.pa`. Hopefully we will get an update that fixes the problem, but this will do until then.

Comment: Actually I think the `initialization failed` error also occurs if the module is already loaded. So that doesn't necessarily mean `udev-detect` completely fails. But yeah, there seems to be some problem with this ...

Comment: Everything was fine for me with 20.04 but a newer kernel.   Updating to 20.10 led to this for me.   Other references online indicated that rolling back alsa and/or pulseaudio did the trick for people with the same hardware on other Linux flavors.   Most of the information I found overlaps with that shared in the main question here.

Comment: Okay, so just adding `load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` finally did it for me. There are still some troubles with microphones, but it mostly works!