# PulseAudio not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

PulseAudio not working in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
Hardware: Laptop Toshiba A665 8 GB Ram

When  I open the sound settings there is not a device to output or input the sound.

[image: pulseAudio not found, no audio devices]

Here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
I founded that this command

```
sudo killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

Restart the audio.
But when I restart the machine the problem continues again.

1) 
I try to solve with his

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

2) After I try to solve with this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa; sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr 'n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

3) After I found someone who said to has the same problem and solved with command

```
pulseaudio
```

It starts the sound but there is possible to make it upper or down the volume.
Also I needed to add this in the start, addind the next line

```
PULSEAUDIO_SYSTEM_START=1
```

In the **/etc/default**

But after restart I have no sound.

I saw this link

No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

4) looking here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting
There is a command to configure a server during runtime is $ pacmd

```
mariano@mariano-Satellite-A665D:~/.config$ pacmd
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

So I started to search about this issue
**No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.**

5) In this site
https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio#Restarting_the_Pulseaudio_Daemon
I found this

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse /tmp/pulse-*
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

It worked. But after restart I had not sound again.

6) I found this questions
[How to make pulseaudio work again?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225444/how-to-make-pulseaudio-work-again)

And I replace my **default.pa** file for the  **default.pa** from the answer.
But after restart again I had not sound.

7) In the other answer from here
[How to make pulseaudio work again?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225444/how-to-make-pulseaudio-work-again)

The second guy said to find another file **default.pa** in the hard disk in order to see if there is another place where the os is taking the values
I found another **default.pa** in the folder 
**/snap/pulseaudio/9/etc/pulse**
But there was no  chance to replace it with the downloaded **default.pa** file

After some days I have not solution yet.
So If anyone can gime some ideas about this problem I will really thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

I too had same issue and I'm not sure what worked for me but after following all steps given at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) link, audio driver issue solved for me.

Comment: thanks a lot Pankaj I reinstall the OS and update to a new version, but if this strange error happen again I will try this.